# How to stop preview from making smoothed lines?

Tags: macos, preview

Whenever I go to handdraw a line, it gets smoothed out and I need to correct it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you get to the point where you see the squiggly icon, you can draw crooked lines and shapes and a pulldown menu will appear under the squiggly line to let you chose between a new shape or line or your original sketch. See image below.

[image]

Comment: You need to do that every time though (At least for me). This works good enough https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/411998/394707